# sorting matrix based on columns comparison

Tags: c#, c, algorithm, sorting

I have a matrix of 50 rows and 2 columns and I want to sort them based on **the comparison of the value of the second column filed**. Here what I mean, if my matrix as:

```
[00][01]
[10][11]
[20][21]
[30][31]
[40][41]
[50][51]
```

I want to compare [01] and [11] and if [01] lesser than [11] I want to exchange the entire second row with the first row, to be like this (for example):

```
[10][11]
[00][01]
[20][21]
[30][31]
[40][41]
[50][51]
```

I tried using C# and came up with this algorithm but it didn't work:

```
 int temp1, temp2;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < 2; j++)
                        {
                            if (rating[i, j] < rating[i + 1, j])
                            {
                                temp1 = rating[i + 1, j - 1];
                                temp2 = rating[i + 1, j];

                                rating[i + 1, j - 1] = rating[i, j - 1];
                                rating[i + 1, j] = rating[i, j];

                                rating[i, j - 1] = temp1;
                                rating[i, j] = temp2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Can someone tell me a key to workout this problem or if you have the answer in c,c++ or another language please share it with us.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of sort algorithm is wrong. The inner loop should not run from i+1 to 1.

Try implementing the simple bubble sort:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 49-i; j++)
  {
    if (rating[j, 1] < rating[j + 1, 1]) // column 1 entry comparison
    {
      temp1 = rating[j, 0];              // swap both column 0 and column 1
      temp2 = rating[j, 1];

      rating[j, 0] = rating[j+1, 0];
      rating[j, 1] = rating[j+1, 1];

      rating[j+1, 0] = temp1;
      rating[j+1, 1] = temp2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Partially it did work. See the picture:
http://im41.gulfup.com/TrGUn.bmp
Where I pointed with red the second column has number 5 which supposed to be the highest values. Should be like this:
.. 5
.. 5
.. 5
.. 5
.. 4
.. 4
.. 4
.......... and so on.

Comment: the full code is so lengthy and complex and only this requirement is remaining to finish the implementation.

Comment: Now it worked like a charm :D. Could you please tell us what was the problem ?

Comment: It is simple bubble sort implementation. The inner loop should start from 0, earlier it was starting from i.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to sort the matrix in descending order of second column. Give this code a try.

```
int[][] mat = new[] { new[] { 4, 4 }, new[] { 5, 1 }, new[] { 3, 2 }, new[] { 6, 1 } };
var ordered = mat.OrderByDescending(i => i[1]);
```