# I want to sort matrix in ascending order in C# without any function

Tags: c#

Matrix entered the result is:

```
                         1    5   48

                         7   11    3
```

P.S User can enter any number not like above.

It should be in ascending order: 1 3 5 7 11 48

I used loop but it does not work properly

```
using System;

namespace MainClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, j, m, n, sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            Console.Write("The MxN matrix\n");
            Console.Write("Enter the number of rows and columns of the matrix :\n");
            Console.Write("Rows (M): ");
            m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Columns (N): ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] arr = new int[m, n];
            Console.Write("Enter elements in the first matrix :\n");

            /* Entering matrix elements */

            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("element - [{0}],[{1}] : ", i, j);
                    arr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    /* Calculating odd numbers of the matrix */

                    if (arr[i, j] % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        sum += arr[i, j];
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\nThe matrix is:\n");
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    Console.Write("{0} ", arr[i, j]);
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            Console.Write("\nThe sum of odd numbers is: {0}", sum);

            /* Sorting Matrix in ascending order*/

            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
                {
                  for (int j1 = 0; j1 < n; j1++ )
                  {
                    if (arr[i, j] > arr[i, j1]){
                      int temp = arr[i, j];
                      arr[i, j] = arr[i, j1];
                      arr[i, j1] = temp;
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\nAscending order: ");
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    Console.Write("{0} ", arr[i, j]);
            }
             Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what means: without any function. Also when posting a question always add your own code so we understand what you tried so far.

Comment: I couldnt paste my code because i am new here. without any function I meant Array.Sort(). I was going to mean using loop.

Comment: Dear Azizbek, when you are new, you should be able to paste your code, please take the time to learn how you need to make a question else other people (who want to help you) cannot help you.

Comment: As I understand you want an example of a code what is sorting numbers, so you understand how you should do this. maybe this helps you: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3460/sort-numbers-in-ascending-order-using-c-sharp.aspx

Comment: here i posted my code

Comment: Dear Aldert thank you for the link but i know this method for array but in my case it is not working

Comment: Your code is not working at all, I cannot fill in numbers, never mind I look at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615106/sorting-matrix-based-on-columns-comparison

Comment: Dear Aldert can you save the code with you for a while please?

Comment: Please be more specific when you say that something doesn't work. You've written "I used loop but it does not work properly", "It did not work" and "your answer did not work right for my code" - which tells us that what you tried didn't work, but nothing about the *way* in which it didn't work. Did it fail to compile? Run but throw an exception? Run but produce the wrong output? In each case, please either tell us the error message or the incorrect output vs the correct output. The more specific you can be able the way in which something doesn't work, the easier it'll be to get it to work.

Comment: sorry Daisy Shipton for the disturbances yes it run but wrong output

Comment: @AzizbekGaybullaev: Again, "but wrong output" doesn't give enough information. What *is* the output, compared with what you expected? Please edit that into the question. (And when you add a comment to say it didn't work, include it there too.)

Comment: Daisy Shipton untill you understand the problem, it has been solved) thank you for trying to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```
using System;
namespace MainClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, j, m, n, sum = 0; int count = 0; Console.Write("The MxN matrix\n"); Console.Write("Enter the number of rows and columns of the matrix :\n"); Console.Write("Rows (M): "); m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); Console.Write("Columns (N): "); n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); int[,] arr = new int[m, n]; Console.Write("Enter elements in the first matrix :\n");

            /* Entering matrix elements */

            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("element - [{0}],[{1}] : ", i, j);
                    arr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    /* Calculating odd numbers of the matrix */

                    if (arr[i, j] % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        sum += arr[i, j];
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\nThe matrix is:\n");
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
                    Console.Write("{0} ", arr[i, j]);
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            Console.Write("\nThe sum of odd numbers is: {0}", sum);

            /* Sorting Matrix in ascending order*/

            for (i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    int row1 = i % m;
                    int col1 = i / m;

                    int row2 = j % m;
                    int col2 = j / m;

                    if (arr[row1, col1] > arr[row2, col2])
                    {
                        int temp = arr[row1, col1];
                        arr[row1, col1] = arr[row2, col2];
                        arr[row2, col2] = temp;
                    }

                }
            }


            Console.Write("\nAscending order: ");
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
                    Console.Write("{0} ", arr[i, j]);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You had a mistake in how you print your items, you had the second dimension as inner for loop, this should be the outer for loop.I fixed it, see answer.

Comment: It is again producing wrong output. Here its output: Ascending order: 3 45 65 7 63 89

Comment: No it is not, if you copy my complete code you will see it works. Not only the sorting part because the problem is not the sorting but the way you "see" the array. You place the second dimension in the first and this is incorrect.

Comment: Look how I changed all your for loops, j is the outer loop and i the inner. You can also see that where you write: "The matrix is:", it is showing the correct Matrix. You can clearly see from your code that when the array is a (3,2) you print a (2,3), this is incorrect and causing in your example the believe that the sorting is incorrect.

Comment: Aldert you are super! Thank you very much! The problem is solved

Comment: Aldert can i ask one more question please?

Comment: )) I would like to show frequencies of numbers in Matrix. e.g User entered 2x2 matrix as follow 1 2 \n 5 2. the output should be 1 occurs 1 times 2 occurs 2 time 5 occurs 1 times and so on. Unfortunately my algorthim does not give me a right answer. for this Can you give me a direction please?

Comment: You can use a dictionary object. As the Key you have the number and as the value the amount it happens. Check if key is in dictionary, if not add it with initial value of zero. Now increace the key by one. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672218(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I used the dictionary before asking you this question. The output was 2 occurs 0 times. All numbers occur 0 times. It did not count. Is there another except dictionary

Comment: I believe you are using it not correct, I propose you post a new question and we go from there..

Comment: Aldert i think there is no need to post here new question.  You posted answer fully. Please from it can you do?

Comment: Hello Azizbek, I want to follow the principles of the great concept of StackOverflow. This means people who need some help from others ask this in the open. If you need help you do the effort of asking the question. Others react and this is creating the community. Let me know your new question and I will do my best to answer :-)

Comment: Thank you Aldert i asked lots of question. I should solve the problem on my own. Thank you very much:)) keep following the rules of SO:-)